# Re-create foldername when generated foldername already exists

Tags: php

If I use this code to create an random foldername I can check if this foldername already exists, but how to run this again create a new foldername and check this again, and so on

```
function createRandomFoldername()
{
    $chars = "abcdefghijkmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1023456789";
    srand((double)microtime()*1000000);
    $i = 0;
    $folder = '' ;

    while ($i <= 10)
    {
        $num = rand() % 33;
        $tmp = substr($chars, $num, 1);
        $folder = $folder . $tmp;
        $i++;
    }

    return $folder;
}
$folder_random = createRandomFoldername();
```

Comment: Adding an `is_dir` `while` inside the function may work here.

Comment: Side note: I'd advise against seeding the random number generator manually, let alone inside a function that can be potentially called several times within the same microsecond.

Comment: What do you mean with seeding @ÁlvaroGonzález

Comment: I mean calling `srand()`. If I recall correctly it used to be necessary in PHP/4 but it has not been the case any more for many years. Additionally, `microtime()` is likely to generate the same value (computers are fast).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your concern is about race conditions, you can try this:

```
!is_dir($folder) && !mkdir($folder) && !is_dir($folder)
```

This code is taken from [Probable bugs](https://github.com/kalessil/phpinspectionsea/blob/master/docs/probable-bugs.md#mkdir-race-condition) documentation for [Php Inspections (EA Extended)](https://github.com/kalessil/phpinspectionsea).

> **'mkdir(...)' race condition**
>
> This issue is difficult to reproduce, as any concurrency-related
>   issues are. It appears when several processes are attempting to create
>   a directory which does not yet exist. Specifically, when one process
>   is between `is_dir()` and `mkdir()` after another process has already
>   managed to create the directory.

Just loop until done.

Comment: There is no risk of infinite loop ?

Comment: @Mcsky That mostly depends on the quality of the random name generator, which I haven't checked (save for the seeding, which is certainly wrong).

Comment: Like this? `!is_dir($folder) && !mkdir($folder) && !is_dir($folder) { return $folder; }`

Answer (score 0):

given your random function you can use a do while loop to achieve this

```
do{ 
    $folder_random = createRandomFoldername();//generate once
}while(is_dir($folder_random));//check if already exists
```

the loop will automatically stops if the folder doesn't exists.